# Pass value of text box to java servlets

Tags: java, servlets

Alright cannot find this anywhere and I was wondering how to grab the values of a text box from a jsp or servlet and display it in another servlet.

Now my issue isn't passing the data and actually displaying it, my issue is that whenever a space is in the value I can only get that first bit of information. For example:

```
<form method="post" action="Phase1Servlet">

  <p>Favorite Place:</p> <input type="text" name="place"></div>

  <input id="submit" type="submit"  value="Submit">

</form>
```

Say The user types in  "The Mall"

in the Servlet I use:

```
String place = request.getParameter("place");
```

Then output the variable place somewhere in my code I only get the word "The"

Do I need to use request.getParameterValues("place"); instead? If so how do I pass the values from servlet to servlet through a hidden field? When I do this:

```
String [] placeArr = request.getParameterValues("place");

out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"place\" value="+ placeArr +">");
```

The hidden field actually stores [Ljava.lang.String;@f61f5c

Do i have to parse this or convert this somehow?

Comment: Seems like the issue is somewhere else, since if I use this on my server(my computer) "String place = request.getParameter("place");" I get the whole String, not just the first part. Don't know though as to why it's happening at your end.  Regards

Comment: This can't be happening. Are you saying that value entered in an HTML text input with space does not appear at the server side as it was entered ? - there is something wrong. Do not use getParameterValues - that is for handling scenarios like a RADIO button group with same name for each input.

Comment: just curious, why do you need a hidden field? isnt it enough to store the value in session once you retrieve it the first time? other than that seems weird that you dont get the whole value, maybe if you see the raw http request being sent could help diagnose the problem. i use a tool called Fiddler (there are many) for this purpose and works quite well

Comment: ring bearer- correct the space screws it up for some reason.. this is only happening in a java servlet though works find in jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
String placeArr = request.getParameterValue("place");
out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"place\" value=\""+ placeArr +"\">");
```

Escape the string in the hidden field

Comment: That actually passes <input type="hidden" name="place" value="The" mall="">  -- I actually solved my own issue by using the getParameterValues and using a for loop to pass all the values in the string in

Comment: request.getParameter("place") should be enough and the space would be URL encoded. What is the complete code in your servlet? and what framework are you using?

Comment: Try this, maybe java is getting the value properly but the field is not, Notice the extra inverted commas. out.println("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"place\" value=\""+ placeArr[0] +"\">");

Answer (score 2):

Are you really sure that when you use

```
String place = request.getParameter("place");
```

the `place` variable contains only word before first space? Because it is rather weird situation. If you want to pass a parameter to another servlet(assuming that another servlet is called from this servlet) you can set a request attribute in first servlet and then dispatch that request to another servlet, for example:

```
request.setAttribute("place", "The mail");
RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( path_to_another_servlet );
dispatcher.forward( request, response );
```

and then in another servlet ypu can use it as:

```
String place = request.getAttribute("place");
```